# How do I clean green and brown substances from the connectors of battery-operated devices?

Tags: maintenance

Battery-operated devices have connectors to take in power from batteries in order to work. However, if the batteries are left there and the devices are not used for a few months or more, green and brown substances can be formed on the connectors.

Are there ways to clean up those substances on the connector without buying a new one or damaging it?

Comment: "green and brown substances" = corrosion FYI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you'll want to have a good pair of gloves, this stuff can be nasty and you don't want it on your skin.  Once the batteries are removed, and disposed of properly. Mix baking soda and water into a paste, and apply it to the affected area using a cotton swab (Q-tip). Leave the paste on the terminals for 5-10 minutes, then wipe it off with a damp cloth. Repeat as necessary. Wipe the terminals with a clean dry cloth, and allow to air dry completely.

Once the terminals are clean, you can apply a contact cleaner like [DeoxIT®](http://www.all-spec.com/products/D100L-2DB.html).

[image: DeoxIT® Bottle with Brush Applicator, 7.4 ml]

Which will further clean the terminals, as well as protect them and restore their conductivity.

If the leakage is not that bad, you may be able to clean it with just the contact cleaner.  For heavy corrosion damage the baking soda paste should remove the bulk of the mess, and the contact cleaner will repair some of the unseen damage to the contacts.

Comment: Are there any good DIY solution that I can make from home (since this place is called Home Improvement)? Thanks.

Comment: @LarryMorries Are you asking if you can make baking soda at home? I think the main ingredient in baking soda, is baking soda.

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet Skyline Chili hot sauce will work.  If you put that stuff on a dirty and patina riddled penny for five minutes, it will be bare clean copper upon wiping it off.

Comment: That a nice one - first time hear that chilli hot sauce can wipe off those green and brown substance.